# DynamoDB fine-grained access control with IdentityPool Id (cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud)

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-dynamodb

I have a multi-tenant application and would like to do FGAC in DynamoDB using Cognito, more specifically I'd like to give all the users from one tenant access to certain rows in a table, and the way I've tried to accomplish this was using the ID of the Identity Pool in the Conditions of my Policy.

| partition key ( Identity Pool Id ) | range key ( Item Id ) |
| --- | --- |
| eu-west-2:5124befe-75b6-4484-b73f-e53df48cf642 | test-item-1 |
| eu-west-2:5124befe-75b6-4484-b73f-e53df48cf642 | test-item-2 |

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/tableName",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
            "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}` can/should be used this way, but it's not working. If I manually input the Identity Pool ID in the policy it works, it's just the expression that is not working.
If this is not possible, are there other ways to do the same thing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083150/271415 in case it's helpful. Also, I wouldn't use * for region and AWS account ID in your resource ARN unless you have a good reason to.

Comment: @jarmod I am indeed going through API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB, I'll try accessing DynamoDB from the frontend with amplify and see if it works, thanks! ( only tomorrow though ).

I've used the * just for the example, in the project only the account ID has a * because it changes depending on the deployed environment ( related to control tower or something, the devops guy said )

Comment: How did this story ended for you? Having exactly the same issue